# How to mock Google Cloud Firestore Fieldvalue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I'm using the `@google-cloud/firestore` package in my NodeJS project and I'm trying to set up some unit tests using Jest. I'm currently mocking the package like this (using a manual mock in the __mocks__ folder):

```
const mockFirestore = {
  collection: jest.fn(() => mockCollection),
};

module.exports = {
  Firestore: jest.fn(() => mockFirestore),
};
```

This works perfectly for mocking queries, but I'm running into an issue when I try to call a function that uses a Firestore FieldValue like this:

```
import {Firestore} from '@google-cloud/firestore';
const firestore = new Firestore();

const main = async () => {
  await firestore
    .collection('foo')
    .doc('bar')
    .set({
      foo: 'baz', 
      updated: Firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }, {merge: true});
}

main();
```

Any ideas or best-practices on how to mock this?
Thanks!

Comment: How did you use `@google-cloud/firestore` package? Show the code under test

Comment: Added more code @slideshowp2

Comment: Are you using `await` syntax in a module scope?

Comment: In the snippet yes, in my code no. I updated the snippet now, but I don't think that specific aspect is really relevent to my question on how to mock FieldValue. I'm specifically looking for a way to mock Firestore.FieldValue, when Firestore is already mocked as a function. @slideshowp2

Answer (score 0):

Just assign mocked static property `FieldValue` and method to `Firestore` class. Use `mock.mockReturnValueOnce()` method to mock the return value of `.serverTimestamp()` method for different test case.

`__mocks__/@google-cloud/firestore/index.js`:

```js
const mockFirestore = {
  collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  doc: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  set: jest.fn(),
};

const MockFirestore = jest.fn(() => mockFirestore);
MockFirestore.FieldValue = {
  serverTimestamp: jest.fn(),
};

module.exports = {
  Firestore: MockFirestore,
};
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
const firestore = new Firestore();

const main = async () => {
  await firestore.collection('foo').doc('bar').set(
    {
      foo: 'baz',
      updated: Firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    },
    { merge: true }
  );
};

export { main };
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from './main';
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

jest.mock('@google-cloud/firestore');

describe('67268943', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    Firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp.mockReturnValueOnce(2021);
    expect(Firestore).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    await main();
    const firestore = new Firestore();
    expect(firestore.collection).toBeCalledWith('foo');
    expect(firestore.doc).toBeCalledWith('bar');
    expect(firestore.set).toBeCalledWith(
      {
        foo: 'baz',
        updated: 2021,
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67268943/main.test.js (10.868 s)
  67268943
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 main.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.589 s
```

Comment: Does this answer helped you?